# Delete document with cursor by passing embedded fileds

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

i wants to delete documents from collection using cursor with pymongo. But i have _id filed as embedded and i have to pass whole _id field for deletion criteria.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "Path" : 0,
        "TriggerName" : "KM_Topzones_In App",
        "userId" : NumberLong(3408661),
        "Date" : "01/09/2017",
        "OfferType" : "NOOFFER"
    },
    "OfferCount" : NumberLong(0),
    "OfferName" : "NoOffer",
    "desktopTop-normal" : NumberLong(1),
    "mrcTop-normal" : NumberLong(1),
    "appPostLoginOverlay-normal" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

Delete query:

```
>>> cursor=col.find()
>>> slice=cursor[0:5]
>>> for doc in slice:
...     print doc['_id']
...     result=col.delete_one({"_id": doc['_id']})
...     result.deleted_count
... 
{u'Date': u'01/09/2017', u'Path': 0, u'OfferType': u'NOOFFER', u'userId': 3408661L, u'TriggerName': u'KM_Topzones_In App'}
0
{u'Date': u'01/09/2017', u'Path': 0, u'OfferType': u'NOOFFER', u'userId': 1587308L, u'TriggerName': u'KM_Topzones_In App'}
0
{u'Date': u'01/09/2017', u'Path': 0, u'OfferType': u'NOOFFER', u'userId': 1049384L, u'TriggerName': u'KM_Topzones_In App'}
0
{u'Date': u'01/09/2017', u'Path': 0, u'OfferType': u'NOOFFER', u'userId': 3029181L, u'TriggerName': u'KM_Topzones_In App'}
0
{u'Date': u'01/09/2017', u'Path': 0, u'OfferType': u'NOOFFER', u'userId': 2884382L, u'TriggerName': u'KM_Topzones_In App'}
0
```

But that is not deleting anything ,is there a way to do it ??

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you need to use the "dot notation" because the [field's order matter here.](http://Order%20of%20keys%20in%20document%20in%20mongo%20query,%20matter%20or%20no?)

```
db.collection.deleteOne({
    "_id.Path": 0, 
    "_id.TriggerName" : "KM_Topzones_In App", 
    "_id.userId" : NumberLong(3408661), 
    "_id.Date" : "01/09/2017", 
    "_id.OfferType" : "NOOFFER"
})
```

In your case you can build the query filter using a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
query = {"_id.{key}".format(key=key): value for key, value in doc['_id'].items()}
```

Then pass the `query` to `.delete_one()`

```
result = col.delete_one(query)
```

Comment: @ Styvane Thanks a ton, but in my case i need small change in `query. i.e query = {"_id.{key}".format(key=key): value for key, value in doc['_id'].items()}`

Comment: @@Styvane,Is it possible to have a condition before delete, i wants it to stop whenever it reaches to a particular date for `_id.Date` field.

Comment: You can select only those documents you wish to delete by using the `_id.Date` field in your query filter. But this will only be useful if you have a valid Date object.